# Boostrap queries visible-xx not showing/hiding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I can't seem to figure out why both image elements (main logo, one small one large) are displaying all the time. ? Specifically, it seemed like all was well until I hear Firefox isn't showing the large logo.

code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="index.html">
  <img id="header-logo" src="img/dmi-logo.png" width="253" height="138" alt=""/>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand visible-md visible-sm visible-xs" href="index.html"> 
  <img id="header-logo-sml" src="img/dmi-logo-sec.png" alt=""/>
</a>
```

I guess the browser renders the code in all cases, but the CSS hides/shows it?

Comment: works fine for me using Bootstrap 3.3.4 in Firefox 36 and 37. 
you're correct, the css hides and shows and element so there are two image requests to the server using this approach.

Comment: great thanks! can you suggest an alternate method, not requiring dual server hits?

Comment: You would need to use the [`<picture>`](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) element and the [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) polyfill. This will NOT prevent all browsers from making 2 requests, but the browser will prioritize the image it needs before the other one is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a Firefox issue you can alternatively you can use hidden-??

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" href="index.html">
    <img id="header-logo" src="img/dmi-logo.png" width="253" height="138" alt=""/>
</a>

<a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs" href="index.html"> 
      <img id="header-logo-sml" src="img/dmi-logo-sec.png" alt=""/>
</a>
```